# How do I see and delete an 'invisible / orhpaned' symbolic link?

Tags: symbolic-link, symlink

There seems to be an invisible symbolic link on my system.

1. First, I go to the `/var/www` directory and it shows nothing:

   ```
   # var/www# ls -la
   total 0
   ```
2. Next, I create a symbolic link and it is created successfully:

   ```
   # var/www# ln -s /var/www/server/ /var/www
   # var/www# ls -la
   total 0
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Aug 23 22:51 server -> /var/www/server/
   ```

   Note: There was no 'server' directory in `/var/www/`
3. I remove the symbolic link:

   ```
   # var/www# rm server
   # var/www# ls -la
   total 0
   ```
4. I create a server directory successfully:

   ```
   # var/www# mkdir server
   # var/www# ls -la
   total 4.0K
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Aug 23 22:52 server
   ```
5. I try to create a symbolic link and get an error:

   ```
   # var/www# ln -s /var/www/server/ /var/www/
   ln: creating symbolic link `/var/www/server': File exists
   ```
6. I look for the symbolic link and it is not there:

   ```
   # var/www# ls -la
   total 4.0K
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Aug 23 22:52 server

   # ls -la server/
   total 0
   ```

The problem: Once I create the `server` folder in `/var/www/` I can no longer successfully create a symbolic link. I have also tried to find orphaned links with these commands:

```
find / -type l -exec ls -l {} \; > links.txt
```

and

```
find -L -type l > links.txt
```

... and I found nothing related to `/var/www`.

I also tried:

```
strace ln -n -s -f /var/www/server /var/www
```

and it returned, in part:

```
write(2, "`/var/www/server' and `/var/www/"..., 57
```

`/var/www/server' and`/var/www/server' are the same file) = 57

No luck. How do I delete the 'invisible' symbolic link?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Of **course** you can't create a directory and symlink with the same name.

Comment: Uh Oh. It's 430am and I think I just got a clue. . . . In the past system setups, I had to change the root html directory from somewhere else (I guess) to /var/www/server . . . Now, without thinking hard enough, I was trying to move the document root from /var/www/ to /var/www/server/ ............ Ouch. "My brain no works."  Revelation: "A symbolic link cannot point from a parent directory to a subdirectory"

Comment: It can, but they can't have the same name ln -s /var/www/server /var/www/server1 would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you carried out the operation at `1.` you created a symbolic link that effectively pointed to itself. If you had tried to use it you would have got an error message e.g.

```
cd server
bash: cd: server: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

or some other depending on how you tried to use it.

At `4.` you created a directory called `server` and at `5.` you tried to create a link called `server`  in the `/var/www` directory - you can't so this as the link can't have the same name as the existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a 'invisible' symlink, it's a folder `/var/www/`. At the first step, you can create a symlink because `/var/www/server` doesn't exist, so it is a 'dead' link. You will see it is highlighted with red color from `ls -l` output.